# Django: failed to run gunicorn

Tags: django, gunicorn

I try to run gunicorn but it failed
I have install gunicorn in my virtual env (pip install gunicorn)

`cd intensetbm_app/intensetbm-etool`
`gunicorn intenseTBM_eTool.wsgi:application`

my project architecture:

```
envs
intensetbm_app
|   intensetbm-etool
|   |   intenseTBM_eTool
|   |   |    wsgi.py
|   |   |    settings.py
|   |   |    ...
|   |   manage.py
|   |   ...
intensetbm_static
```

wsgi.py

```
import os

from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application

os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'intenseTBM_eTool.settings')

application = get_wsgi_application()
```

trace (partial):

```
...
  File "/home/test/intensetbm_app/intensetbm-etool/intenseTBM_eTool/wsgi.py", line 12, in <module>
    from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'django'
[2020-03-18 15:00:20 +0000] [43251] [INFO] Worker exiting (pid: 43251)
[2020-03-18 15:00:20 +0000] [43248] [INFO] Shutting down: Master
[2020-03-18 15:00:20 +0000] [43248] [INFO] Reason: Worker failed to boot.
```

Comment: Did you install Django to your virtual env?

Comment: yes all is running

Comment: settings.py : WSGI_APPLICATION = 'intenseTBM_eTool.wsgi.application'

Comment: Is django listed in `python3 -m pip freeze` when you have your virtual env activated?

Comment: yes Django==2.2.5 as well as gunicorn==20.0.4

Comment: @SLATER what is output for `which gunicorn`?

Comment: /home/test/envs/envTbm/bin/gunicorn

Comment: which pip : /home/test/envs/envTbm/bin/pip